# psql LTRIM is trimming characters I did not specify

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am new to psql and I have a sql file that I am practicing with.

If I type the following:

```
 select log.path from log where log.status not like '404 NOT FOUND';
```

I arrive at this:

```
                path
------------------------------------
 /article/bears-love-berries
 /article/bad-things-gone
 /article/trouble-for-troubled
 /
 /article/bad-things-gone
 /article/so-many-bears
 /article/bears-love-berries
 /
 /article/bears-love-berries
 /article/so-many-bears
 /article/goats-eat-googles
 /article/trouble-for-troubled
 /
 /article/goats-eat-googles
 /
 /article/bad-things-gone
 /
 /article/media-obsessed-with-bears
 /article/bears-love-berries
 /article/candidate-is-jerk
```

I am trying to trim /article/ off of the results.
If I type the following:

```
select ltrim(log.path, '/article/') from log where log.status not like '404 NOT FOUND';
```

This is the result:

```
           ltrim
---------------------------
 bears-love-berries
 bad-things-gone
 ouble-for-troubled

 bad-things-gone
 so-many-bears
 bears-love-berries

 bears-love-berries
 so-many-bears
 goats-eat-googles
 ouble-for-troubled

 goats-eat-googles

 bad-things-gone

 media-obsessed-with-bears
 bears-love-berries
 ndidate-is-jerk
```

Some of them are not trimming correctly or there's something about it I'm not understanding. I've spent hours researching and trying different methods of doing it but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html

> LTRIM will "remove the longest string containing only characters from characters"

```
select ltrim('zzzytest', 'xyz') 
Result: 'test'
```

So you are not going to be replacing the single text entry like you think it is. It is going to remove characters from the string not necessarily just the one thing you want to remove.

So in this instance with one of your messed up string outputs

> /article/candidate-is-jerk

is turning into

> ndidate-is-jerk

You might be better off using replace if you are trying to remove only a specific string from a sentence. The syntax for replace is: 
replace('STRING OR COLUMN','text you would like to replace','text you want to replace with')

```
select replace('/article/candidate-is-jerk', '/article/', '')
Result: "candidate-is-jerk"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in a way for me to understand. The documentation can sometimes be confusing to read. This worked terrifically.

Comment: You are very welcome. I sometimes have the same issue where the docs aren't as clear as they could be. Have fun on your journey!

Answer (score 0):

`ltrim` does not do exactly what you think. It starts from the left and trims any symbol occurring in `/article/`, which means it also cuts away `tr` from `trouble` because `t` and `r` are part of `/article/`. Use `substring()` instead, it also supports pattern matching.